# create map that contains all keys with the same letters with all values

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

This is a object

```js
var obj = {
    abc: 'xyz', 
    a: 12, 
    cba: 'xyz2', 
    ba: 22, 
    ab: 33, 
    abcde: 44 
};
```

and its what `console.log(flatSimilarKeys(obj));` prints:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvMRO.png]

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the key, sort it and join it with an empty string. Then collect the values.

```js
function flatSimilarKeys(object) {
    var result = Object.create(null);           // without prototypes

    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var key = k.split('').sort().join('');

        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(object[k]);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(flatSimilarKeys({ abc: 'xyz', a: 12, cba: 'xyz2', ba: 22, ab: 33, abcde: 44 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```